# Save class field in particular order in Spring couchbase

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, couchbase

I am using couchbase as Spring-data in Spring boot application,
I am saving a class let say ***Employee***
which contain fields ***empId, empName, empDesc*** etc.
I wanted to save this object in couchbase in particular order.
Lets say I wanted to save this json in couchbase in the order

```
{
  "empName": "hello",
  "empDesc": "helloDesc",
  "empId": "hello11"
}
```

How can I can acheive this?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why? This sounds like an XY Problem to me. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the point. Order of keys is irrelevant in a JSON object, be it in Couchbase or not.

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

Cf http://json.org/

If the order is so important to you, you should use a JSON Array.
Don't use an API or framework in a devious way, it usually ends bad.